# Trying to build react library but keep getting Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi guys Im working on my first React library:
Here it is:

https://github.com/HunterJS-bit/react-mini-contextmenu

But when I try to npm install it, I get error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

I do not know what to change next I tried changing adding default export in my index.ts
Like this:

```
import ContextMenu from './components/ContextMenu';

export default ContextMenu;
```

But it is still not working as expected, getting same error :/

has anyone had simmilar issue because I do not see how can I solve this

Comment: try to change ```const ContextMenu``` to ```export const ContextMenu``` and remove ```export default ContextMenu``` from ContextMenu.tsx and in index.ts use ```import { ContextMenu } from './components/ContentMenu'``` and ```export default ContextMenu```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this:-

```
import { default as ContextMenu } from './components/ContextMenu';

export default ContextMenu;
```

or

> Check for your webpack config's output path. That should be the
>   problem if the above solution doesn't work.

Try adding this to you rules:-

```
  {
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
  }
```

OR

```
  {
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    use: 'ts-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
  },
```

You can try both too.

Comment: Hi here is how my webpack config looks, I think all looks fine: https://github.com/HunterJS-bit/react-mini-contextmenu/blob/master/webpack.prod.config.js

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using babel-loader for TS files, you need to use either ts-loader or awesome typescript loader. as follows:-

Comment: yes missing.. awesome typescript loader, i install it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this
in your index.ts

```
export * from './components/ContextMenu';//to reexport the name exports
export {default} from './components/ContextMenu';// to reexport the default exports
```

Instead of importing and exporting again

Comment: But why event when event is not exported from ContextMenu ?

Comment: try the update answer now. and is your library in npmjs?

Comment: yes it is here it is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mini-contextmenu

Comment: Not working I packed my app & installed it locally same error :/ Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: could it be issue with webpack ?\

Comment: dont know much about react and webpack issuesc but here i doubt there should be class ...dont you think in ContextMenu file --> const ContextMenu = (props: any) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({

Comment: But I wanted a functional component not a class so I can use hooks

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are exporting a element instead of a component. Export the component instead.

Comment: What do you mean ??? How could I change that, have you seen the source code: https://github.com/HunterJS-bit/react-mini-contextmenu/blob/master/src/index.ts ????